# How to make scrollbars for a canvas in Processing

Tags: processing

I am working on a data visualization using Processing. I am not able to fit all the desired content on the canvas, so instead of increasing the canvas size, I want to use scrollbars for scrolling down through the screen(canvas). I needed help with the coding, since I have never done coding for scrollbars before. All help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Amrita

Answer (score 1):

Make the webpage do the work for you, by putting your canvas in a fixed size div.

```
<div style="width: 400px; height: 400px; overflow: auto;">
  <canvas id="mycanvas" data-processing-sources="mysketch.pde file2.pde ...">
  </canvas>
</div>
```

The web page will now automatically give you scrollbars for canvas, if you use a size() that's bigger than 400x400

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking at doing this entirely in the sketch, I think that you'll need the [translate(x, y)](http://processing.org/reference/translate_.html) function. To scroll up by `x` pixels, use the code `translate(0, -x);`.  This will only work on stuff drawn *after* calling the function. See the link I gave you above to look at its behaviour. ([http://processing.org/ reference/ translate_.html](http://processing.org/reference/translate_.html)).

Making the scrollbars themselves so they can be dragged will be hard. Consider the mouse scroll wheel or up-down buttons not bars. A bar which cannot be dragged, but which can be looked at to see position and moved with up-down buttons, is a good compromise, even if it's an odd UI.